# Rails - Add games Association to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an association between Users and Games, Users can favorite or associate Games to their profile. But I got an issue with the routes or the link (I guess, maybe its something else).

I have a join table between Users and Games :

> Game_User with games ID and User ID

The association is working fine in the console when I do this.

```
@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
@game = Game.find(params[:id])
@user.games << @game
```

**games_controller.rb:**

```
def favorite
  game = Game.find(params[:id])
  current_user.games << game
  flash[:notice] = 'You favorited #{@game.name}'
  redirect_to games_url
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "games" => "games#index"
post "games/:id" => 'games#favorite'
```

And I would like to do the same with my link.

Here is the list of the games, and for each a link to favorite them :

```
<% if current_user %>
    <% @games.each do |game| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= game.name %></td>
        <td><%= game.plateform %></td>
        <td><%= game.typegame %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', game %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(game) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', game, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <td>  <%= link_to "favorite", games_path, type: "favorite", method: :post %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is : Creating the association between user and game(s) , when i click on the link Favorite, it's generating a new Game (def create game.new ... )

Comment: Do you get an error or what? What's your actual problem?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, actually, when i click on the link , it's generating a new game for the list, and not just adding a game to the user. That"s why i think i got a problem of path or route ;) the "favorite" action is not happening.

Comment: Can you show me what `rake routes` outputs? My guess is that POST to `games_path` goes somewhere else

Comment: Yes i got 2 "POST" >  POST   /games(.:format)                games#create and the other one    POST   /games/:id(.:format)            games#favorite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `games_path` in your `link_to` method, but that will give you `games#create` instead of `favorite`. You need to tell Rails what name you'd like to use, with a named route: `post "games/:id/" => 'games#favorite', as: :favorite_game` and use `favorite_game_path(game)` in your view.

Comment: Thanks it's seems to work , my "notice" is not taking the name of the game (renders  'You favorited #{@game.name}'  I hope he's taking an ID, but anyway, thank you very much ;)  , great answer

Comment: You have to use `" ` Strings for interpolation to work. Change it to `flash[:notice] = "You favorited #{@game.name}"`

Comment: Thanks PoloniculMov , I will try this ;) . I also added the uniqueness of the relationship between games and users  Thanks again